# Segmentation Fault when adding Null terminator to string

Tags: c, string

Task from University: new_string should be copied to next_string->characters, but there is only MAX_STR_LENGTH chars alloced for next_string->characters, so new string is cutted in the if statement (36), adding a null terminator to the string. As soon as new_string has the same lenght as MAX_STR_LENGTH and the if statement is true, **I get a segmentation fault in row 38.** I don't understand why, because due to the if statement, there must be and index MAX_STR_LENGTH-1. Also: strlen does not count \0, so everything should be fine?

````
 22     string* next_string;
 23     // (Allokierung und Prüfung des Speichers)
 24     // TODO: Implementieren Sie hier Ihre Lösung
 25         if((next_string = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string)))==NULL){
 26                 exit(1);
 27         }
 28         if((next_string->characters = (char*)malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH*sizeof(char)))==NULL){
 29                 exit(1);
 30         }
 31     // die Zeichenkette abschneiden
 32     int length = strlen(new_string);
 33         printf("%d", length);
 34     // TODO: Implementieren Sie hier Ihre Lösung um zu lange Zeichenketten
 35     // abzuschneiden
 36         if(length > MAX_STRING_LENGTH-1){
 37                 length = MAX_STRING_LENGTH-1;
 38                 new_string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH-1] = '\0';
 39                 //snprintf(new_string, , "%s",new_string);
 40         }
 41
 42     next_string->length = length;
 43     strncpy(next_string->characters, new_string, length+1/* TODO */);
 44
 45     return next_string;```
 46 }
````

Comment: don't do `strlen(new_string)` until you put the details in it

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us (with emphasis of the minimal part), and [edit] your question to include it. And don't include line-numbers, the perfect [mre] should be possible to copy-paste (without any editing) by us to replicate the exact problem you have. If you want to emphasize a specific line add comments around it.

Comment: What is `new_string`? something produced by a string literal (`"abc"`)?

Comment: Where is the `new_string` coming from? What `next_string = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string))` is the size of `string`? Share the all relevant code.

Comment: The question is: Where is `new_string` stored? If it is stored in read-only memory (this is the default for string constants in modern OSs), you cannot overwrite `new_string`. If you attempt to do it anyway, you'll get a segmentation fault!

Comment: Tip: `strlen` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show how `new_string` is initialized, but I bet you have something equivalent to

```c
char *new_string = "abc";
```

It is undefined behaviour to modify a string produced by a string literal.

Remove the offending line and use the following to copy the string into the buffer:

```c
if ( length >= MAX_STRING_LENGTH )
   length = MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 1;

next_string->length = length;

if ( length )
   strncpy( next_string->characters, new_string, MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 1 );

next_string->characters[ length ] = 0;
```

Also, you should make `new_string` a `const char *` instead of a `char *`.

Comment: Yess exactly! I thought a static string would behave as a statically initialized int array, but it doesn't. What benefits does const char give me, or what could go wrong if I just use char?

Comment: You would have gotten a compile-time error instead of undefined behaviour (which manifested itself as a segfault) at runtime.

Comment: `char new_string[] = "abc";` would creates a modifiable array.